# How to add a multiple uibutton inside a UITextView in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, uitextview

In my app I like to add a multiple `UIButton` inside a `UITextView`, now I add `UIButton` using single object but I change any `UIButton` it change apply to all `UIButton`, how I solve it?

```
-(void)Check

{
    CGPoint origin = note.frame.origin;
    NSString* head = [note.text substringToIndex:note.selectedRange.location];
    CGSize initialSize = [head sizeWithFont:note.font constrainedToSize:note.contentSize];
    NSUInteger startOfLine = [head length];

    NSString* tail = [head substringFromIndex:startOfLine];
    CGSize lineSize = [tail sizeWithFont:note.font forWidth:note.contentSize.width lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGPoint cursor = origin;
    cursor.x += lineSize.width+15;
    cursor.y += initialSize.height - lineSize.height-130;

    myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    myButton.frame=CGRectMake(cursor.x, cursor.y, 15, 15);
    Chkimg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk.png"];
    [myButton setBackgroundImage:Chkimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ChcK) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [note addSubview:myButton];
}
```

Comment: Please formulate the answer in a better way.

Comment: Where are you change the attribute of the button. You care crating a new button and adding it to text view

Answer (score 0):

Use `button.tag` property to distinguish among your all button.

and can perform task according tagValue

```
if(button.tag==0)
{
//do somthing
}
else
{
//do other thing
}
```